# Force activity to start from history

Tags: android, android-activity, android-menu

Is it possible to force an `Activity` to start from history (if it exists in history, of course), even if it is started from menu or home screen? In other words, I want to always load my application from history, if this history exists, irrespectively of how it was called.

Comment: You can store a reference to your last activity in a database for example and when launching your app you could check the database for your last activity.

Comment: What do you mean by "start from history"? Please explain in more detail

Answer (score 1):

You can add [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) to intent when you start activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
startActivity(intent);
```